# Compiling PHP with cURL and SSL support on Redhat EC5

Tags: php, ssl, redhat, curl

I don't even know where to begin to be honest.

Trying to use an external API that requires SSL connections, I discover that SSL in needed on cURL, but this (apparently) requires PHP to be reinstalled and compiled with cURL / SSL support.

Not really experienced with compiling PHP, and I'm not sure if our server even has make or build, the only luck I've had is with rpm's before.

This really isn't in my job description. Any help most most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you have redhat.. and fine with the stock php it includes

```
yum install php-curl
```

Then restart apache

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: Or just `killall -HUP httpd`.

Comment: Loaded plugins: security
epel                                                     | 3.4 kB     00:00
dries                                                    |  951 B     00:00
rpmforge                                                 | 1.1 kB     00:00
primary.xml.gz                                           | 3.6 MB     00:02
rpmforge                                                       10064/10064
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package php-curl available.
Nothing to do

- I don't seem to have any of the stock RHEL repositories.

Comment: Then you are not running a registered version of redhat. You can use to the CentOS yum repos